# How to stop execution flow when a Dialog box is open in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am developing an Android application the allows to users to sign in with their Google accounts, when the user sign in with his Google account a Dialog box should appear to ask him to introduce some data (Age and gender).

Here is my DialogBox class:

```
public class DialogBox extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

private static final String TAG =  DialogBox.class.getSimpleName();

private Button okButton;
private Spinner ageSpinner;
private RadioButton radioDialogMale;
private RadioButton radioDialogFemale;
private String selectedAge;

private Communicator communicator;
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateDialog(Bundle) - Ini ");


    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateDialog(Bundle) -  Fi ");
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);


}

public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

    communicator  = (Communicator) activity;
}

public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView(LayoutInflaterm ViewGroup, Bundle) - Ini ");

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_box_layout, null);

    ageSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.age_spinner_dialog);
    ageSpinner.setSelected(false);
    ageSpinner.setAdapter(populateAgeSpinner());
    ageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    radioDialogMale = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioDialogM);
    radioDialogMale.setSelected(false);
    radioDialogMale.setOnClickListener(this);
    radioDialogFemale = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioDialogF);
    radioDialogFemale.setSelected(false);
    radioDialogFemale.setOnClickListener(this);

    okButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    setCancelable(false);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView(LayoutInflaterm ViewGroup, Bundle) - Fi ");

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onClick(View) - Ini ");
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.radioDialogF:
            radioDialogFemale.setSelected(true);
            break;
        case R.id.radioDialogM:
            radioDialogMale.setSelected(true);
            break;
        case R.id.dialog_ok:

            if(validate()) {

                String gender = "M";
                if(radioDialogFemale.isSelected()) {
                    gender =  "F";
                }

                communicator.onDialogValues(gender,Integer.parseInt(selectedAge));
            }
            break;


    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onClick(View) - Ini ");
}

// To fill the age spinner
public ArrayAdapter<Integer> populateAgeSpinner () {

    Log.d(TAG ,"populateAgeSpinner - Ini");

    List age =  new ArrayList<String>();
    age.add("");

    for(int i =  18; i <= 100; i++) {
        age.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> spinnerAgeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(getActivity(),R.layout.spinner_item_layout, age);
    spinnerAgeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Log.d(TAG ,"populateAgeSpinner - Fi");

    return spinnerAgeAdapter;

}

public boolean validate() {
    Log.d(TAG ,"validate() - Ini");

    boolean result =  true;

    if(selectedAge.equals(null) || selectedAge.isEmpty()) {
        TextView errorText = (TextView)ageSpinner.getSelectedView();
        errorText.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.Error_register_age));
        result =  false;
    }

    if(!radioDialogFemale.isSelected() && !radioDialogMale.isSelected()) {

        radioDialogFemale.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.Error_register_gender));
        radioDialogMale.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.Error_register_gender));
        result =  false;
    }

    Log.d(TAG ,"validate() - Fi");

    return result;

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    selectedAge = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}



 public   interface  Communicator {
         void onDialogValues(String gender, int age);
    }
}
```

and here is the Activity where the Dialog box is called to be shown:

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener
        ,DialogBox.Communicator
{


     ................


  protected void updateActivity(FirebaseUser user) {
        Log.d(TAG ,"updateActivity(FirebaseUser) - Ini");

        if(user != null) {
            ArrayList<String> providers = (ArrayList<String>) user.getProviders();
           if(!providers.isEmpty() && providers.get(0).equals("google.com")) {
               username = user.getEmail().substring(0,user.getEmail().indexOf('@'));
               username =  "mary";
               String userId = user.getUid();
               final boolean[] exist = {false};
               DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();
               Query query = databaseReference.child("Users").orderByChild(userId).equalTo(userId);

               query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       for(DataSnapshot userSnapShot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                           if (!userSnapShot.getKey().equals(null) && !userSnapShot.getKey().isEmpty()) {
                               exist[0] = true;

                           }
                       }
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                   }
               });


               if(!exist[0]) {
                  // DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();
                    showDialog();
               }

           }


            Intent i  =  new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        Log.d(TAG ,"updateActivity(FirebaseUser) - Fi");

    }

    public void showDialog() {

        Log.d(TAG, "showDialog(View) - Ini");

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

        DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();
        dialog.show(manager,"DialogBox");

        Log.d(TAG, "showDialog(View) - Ini");
    }


    @Override
    public void onDialogValues(String sexe, int age) {
        gender = sexe;
        selectedAge = String.valueOf(age);
    }
}
```

The Dialog box is shown but the execution does not stop and the line :

```
  Intent i  =  new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
```

is executed, so the other activity starts and the user has no time to introduce the data requested in the Dialog Box.

I will appreciate any help to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make your activity to implement the `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener` and then inside the `onDismiss` method create the intent for the next activity and start it.

```
  Intent i  =  new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

Comment: Did you remove the 

` Intent i  =  new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
`
from the `updateActivity()` method?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Answer (score 0):

The finish code will run always as the dialog opening doesn't prevent the code from going on.

So, you have to run the finish code in the dismiss method of the `DialogFragment()` NOT in the `updateActivity()` method:

```
public void showDialog() {

    Log.d(TAG, "showDialog(View) - Ini");

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

    DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();
    dialog.show(manager, "DialogBox");
    dialog.onDismiss(dismiss());

    Log.d(TAG, "showDialog(View) - Ini");
}

private DialogInterface dismiss() {
    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    return null;
}
```